# Pymacs Cannot Find Packages on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pymacs

I noticed Pymacs did not recognize packages that were installed through Anaconda.

Note: Just discovered a solution, I will enter it as an answer.

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting realized, through `ps -eaf | grep python`

```
user     5316  5180 47 14:45 pts/3    00:00:04 /usr/bin/python -c import sys; from Pymacs import main; main(*sys.argv[1:]) -f
```

Therein lies the problem, Anaconda sort of takes over as *the* default interpreter on your computer, but Pymacs is still trying to use the global Python under `/usr/bin`. Therefore anything installled through conda install are not visible to Pymacs.

The solution is editing `PYMACS/pymacs.el` file, go to line 623, and change `pymacs-python-command` to `"[YOUR HOME DIR]/anaconda/bin/python"`